# Why does the Win32 MAX_PATH limitation still exist?

Tags: winapi, file-io

Is there a reason why Microsoft doesn't just step in and fix the MAX_PATH limitation in newer versions of Windows? By the looks of it, one could even hook CreateFile and reimplement it in terms of NtCreateFile with a full 32K canonical path length (and virtually unlimited un-canonized path).

(Ditto for other APIs.)

Comment: Um, CreateFile does not have a MAX_PATH limit.

Comment: Additionally: MS won't fix issues like this because it can break a lot of released software.

Comment: `CreateFile` is documented as having a `MAX_PATH` limit, even though you can get around it with the `\\?\` hack. And yah, fixing it'll break a lot of software, Microsoft's first and foremost.

Comment: @RaymondChen MSDN says CreateFileA version is, and if I use CreateFileW with \\?\, I lose path processing

Comment: An application that is still using ANSI should work on converting to Unicode before worrying about `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yep. My concern is about the path processing I'm losing by accepting the \\?\ solution (which is probably half-way to using NtCreateFile directly, right?)

Comment: Yes, you lose out on things like relative paths and other Win32 path normalization steps. There would have to be some new syntax to say "I want Win32 normalization to occur, but operate on NT paths."

Comment: @RaymondChen I couldn't avoid but noticing "notepad \\?\c:\foo\..\foo\test.txt" works just as well as "notepad \\?\c:\foo\test.txt". What is behind Notepad's magic?

Comment: That is still an absolute path. A relative path would be \\?\relative.txt

Comment: @RaymondChen I didn't mean to say it's absolute, but rather that it contains ".." which wouldn't be normalized when prefixed with \\?\, i.e. CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\c:\\foo\\..\\foo\\test.txt", ...) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, but Notepad groks it just fine